# Core Data Sync with iCloud

Tags: ios, nspersistentstore

Problem occurring syncing my `CoreData` to `iCloud`. After getting data from `iCloud` it is not merged with `CoreData`.

> PFUbiquitySetupAssistant validateOptionsWithError:: CoreData: Ubiquity:  Invalid option: the value for NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey should not contain periods:

Comment: Did you search for that error?

Comment: Doesn't that tell you exactly what the problem is? When you create your persistent store you have a key `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey`. You have dots it in (probably a reverse domain name) and Apple says you shouldn't, i.e., don't say "com.domain.appname", say "appname".

Comment: This is answered on Apple dev forum by an Apple engineer. Refer the [complete Q&A here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/865393). You require to login with Apple id.

Comment: i have seen this but this is not work in my project